# Can a tcp port break in hardware?

Tags: mysql, docker, port

I have a student who can start mysql like so

```
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -dp 3306:3306 mysql:latest
```

and connect to is on port 3000.
Any other port works as well, however the following command leads to an authentication issue

```
docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -dp 3000:3306 mysql:latest
```

I have no clue what this could imply. the docker container image is restartet without any volume mount. All other ports work just fine. The error is not a timeout but an auth issue.

Is there some way that the port could break, does that even make sense?

Answer (score 0):

No a TCP port cannot be broken, only something else could be listening on that port so it isn't available (or you are routed to something you don't know about).

See if there is anything listening on the port already, on windows:

```
netstat -aonp tcp | findstr "3000"
```

That will show if something is already listening (maybe another instance or another container).